# How to rename(or move) variable in Lua?

Tags: lua

I would like to rename some variables in Lua for ease of use.

I can simply create aliases using different names but I'm concerned that some memory will be wasted.

In this case, can I simply assign `nil` to old variables?

Here's my example code: (trying to rename `my.tab` to `myTab`)

```
print(type(my.tab))
myTab = my.tab
my.tab = nil
print(type(my.tab))
print(type(myTab))
```

Result:

```
table
nil
table
```

While this way seems to work, I would like to ask if this is a safe and proper way to rename variables in Lua.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's safe (unless you later try to access it through `my.tab`), and I suppose it's proper, but it won't really affect your memory usage. In Lua, all mutable types are reference types. `tab` isn't stored directly in `my`; a reference to it is stored there, and a reference to the same table is now stored in `myTab`. There's an extremely minor memory benefit from setting the old name to `nil` in that `my` will have one fewer hash table entry, and it might (though probably won't) lead to the freeing of the string value `"tab"`, but having two references to the table already wasn't causing you to have two copies of the table.

Incidentally, the more appropriate way to do this would be to declare `myTab` as `local`, since then it wouldn't need to be looked up in the global table, and would be less likely to be accidentally leaked. Not mandatory, though.